# Can't call a method of a view object inside an activity

Tags: java, android, methods, view, android-activity

In my program I have a custom view object.  Inside the view class is a method called foo.  For some reason when I call foo from my activity, it doesn't fire.  Here is the code:

XML of the custom view:

```
<com.company.application.MyView
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The activity code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    MyView mView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);   
        mView= (MyView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_view);

        //A button to fire the method inside foo()
        Button switchLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switch_left);
        switchLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public void callTest() {
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "clicked left arrow");
        mView.foo();
        mView.postInvalidate();

    }
}
```

Finally here is foo:

```
public void foo() {
    mBackground = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.temp_canvas);
    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "background set");
}
```

The first log is always written when the button is pressed, but the second log is not because foo never fires.  What is the deal here?

Thanks in advance all.

**Edit: upon request, the full view**

```
public class MyView extends View {

    Drawable mBackground;

    Context mContext;

    public MyView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mBackground = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.leftarrow1);
    }

    public MyView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        mBackground = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.leftarrow1);
    }

    public void foo() {
        mBackground = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.temp_canvas);
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "background set");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        // draw a solid blue circle
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(20, 20, 15, paint);

        // draw a test background
        mBackground.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 400);
        mBackground.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code of MyView

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive.  Thanks!

Comment: This might be obvious but did you try walking through the code with the debugger? And if that's not possible, did you try to write to the log before setting the background (but within foo) and also with another log-level (e.g. debug or info)?

Comment: @Matthias, yes I did.  It all seemed to check out fine, but I guess it was en emulator issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting the emulator, foo() is now getting called, it just doesn't set the background properly...but that is another problem.